# log4j2 in Java project - Can't find output

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, logfiles

Im new here, Please help me to understand my new project's **log4j2** configuration.

My question is:

- How to get all Log outputs?
- From where should I search log files?

Also how to save tomcat console outputs in the **txt** file?

I really appreciate your help and support, Today I want to learn something new from you guys! Thanks!

This is the `log4j2.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration status="error" monitorInterval="1800">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_HOME">\Workspaces\logs\paymentweb</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_DEBUG">${LOG_HOME}\app\debug.log</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_INFO">${LOG_HOME}\app\info.log</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_ERROR">${LOG_HOME}\app\error.log</Property>
    </Properties>


    <appenders>

        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        （onMismatch）-->
            <ThresholdFilter level="trace" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>

            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z} %-5level %class{36}.%M()/%L - %msg%xEx%n"/>
        </Console>


        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="app_debug" fileName="${LOG_DEBUG}" append="false" filePattern="${LOG_HOME}\$${date:yyyy-MM}\debug-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="debug" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z} %-5level %class{36}.%M()/%L - %msg%xEx%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>


        <CustomRollingRandomAccessFile name="app_info" fileName="${LOG_INFO}" append="false" filePattern="${LOG_HOME}\$${date:yyyy-MM}\info-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z} %-5level %class{36}.%M()/%L - %msg%xEx%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </CustomRollingRandomAccessFile>


        <CustomRollingRandomAccessFile name="app_error" fileName="${LOG_ERROR}" append="false" filePattern="${LOG_HOME}\$${date:yyyy-MM}\error-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z} %-5level %class{36}.%M()/%L - %msg%xEx%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </CustomRollingRandomAccessFile>
    </appenders>


    <loggers>

        <root level="trace" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>  
            <appender-ref ref="app_debug"/>  
            <appender-ref ref="app_info"/>  
            <appender-ref ref="app_error"/>
       </root>
    </loggers>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: I do have a log4j2 configuration on my project and I don't know if it can be used the way you do but I guess that you need to define the loggers section with one appender and then define different components. For example: `<Root level="debug"><AppenderRef ref="Console"/></Root> <Logger name="fully.qualified.classname" additivity="FALSE" level="error"><AppenderRef ref="app_debug"/></Logger>`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Btw, you are spliting the files depending on the logger level and that is normally done initiating your service with different log4j configuration files (and on the application you print the messages on different logger levels)

Answer (score 0):

all your logs are in \Workspaces\logs\paymentweb\app*.log

Comment: I'm running my project and posting some data for log files, but when I check this location its empty

Answer (score 0):

You can find out details about how your appenders are configured by enabling internal Log4j2 "status" logging.

At the top of your configuration file, change it to TRACE `<configuration status="trace" monitorInterval="1800">`. I believe this will show the full path of the file appenders on the console. (No guarantees for the custom appender `CustomRollingRandomAccessFile`.)

Also, you have a non-XML compliant snippet inside the `<Console>` appender configuration. This looks bad and should be removed:

```
（onMismatch）-->
```